# How do I change padding in flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to recreate this page using HTML and CSS:
[image]

However, I cant seem to get the padding changed for the box on the right. This is what mine looks like so far: [image]

How do I adjust the CSS so that the text doesnt have that big white gap on top? Here is my code:

```css
 .flexbox {
      margin: 1rem 6rem;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      font-family: 'Poppins', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI',
        Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
      /* background-color: grey; */
    }
    
    .ten {
      height: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      flex-basis: 40%;
      font-size: 25vw;
      letter-spacing: -3rem;
    }

    .yrs-exp {
      min-height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex-basis: 18%;
    }

    .yrs-exp p {
      margin-bottom: 2rem;
    }

    .yrs-exp button {
      text-transform: capitalize;
      height: 7vh;
      width: 80%;
    }

    .deats {
      display: flex;
      min-height: 100%;
      flex-basis: 30%;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      text-align: center;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .deat {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex-basis: 49%;

      border: solid 1px black;
    }

    .deat h2 {
      font-size: 6vw;
      margin-bottom: -0.8rem;
    }
    .deat p {
      text-transform: uppercase;
      margin-top: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
      <div class="ten">10</div>
      <div class="yrs-exp">
        <h1>Years of experience</h1>
        <p>
          DreamSoft is a team of highly experienced app designers and developers
          creating unique software for you.
        </p>
        <button>GET IN TOUCH</button>
      </div>
      <div class="deats">
        <div class="deat">
          <h2>2k</h2>
          <p>Apps developed</p>
        </div>
        <div class="deat">
          <h2>40</h2>
          <p>Consultants</p>
        </div>
        <div class="deat">
          <h2>12</h2>
          <p>Awards</p>
        </div>

        <div class="deat">
          <h2>160</h2>
          <p>Employees</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And here it is in a codepen: https://codepen.io/caseycling/pen/yLVdzja

Comment: Have you tried `margin-top: 0` on the `h2` elements?

Answer (score 0):

I made a few more changes:

```css
.flexbox {
      margin: 1rem 6rem;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      font-family: 'Poppins', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI',
        Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
      /* background-color: grey; */
    }

    /* .flexbox > div {
      background-color: rgb(206, 89, 89);
    } */

    .ten {
      height: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      flex-basis: 40%;
      font-size: 25vw;
      letter-spacing: -3rem;
    }

    .yrs-exp {
      min-height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex-basis: 18%;
    }

    .yrs-exp p {
      margin-bottom: 2rem;
    }

    .yrs-exp button {
      text-transform: capitalize;
      height: 7vh;
      width: 80%;
    }

    .deats {
      display: flex;
      min-height: 100%;
      flex-basis: 30%;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      text-align: center;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .deat {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-basis: 49%;
      height: 150px;
      border: solid 1px black;
    }

    .deat h2 {
      font-size: 6vw;
      margin: 0;
    }
    .deat p {
      text-transform: uppercase;
      margin-top: 0;
    }

    .clients {
      display: flex;
      margin: 1rem 6rem;
      justify-content: space-around;
    }

    .clients img {
      opacity: 0.5;
      border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }

    .clients img:hover {
      opacity: 1;
      border: solid 1px rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
      <div class="ten">10</div>
      <div class="yrs-exp">
        <h1>Years of experience</h1>
        <p>
          DreamSoft is a team of highly experienced app designers and developers
          creating unique software for you.
        </p>
        <button>GET IN TOUCH</button>
      </div>
      <div class="deats">
        <div class="deat">
          <h2>2k</h2>
          <p>Apps developed</p>
        </div>
        <div class="deat">
          <h2>40</h2>
          <p>Consultants</p>
        </div>
        <div class="deat">
          <h2>12</h2>
          <p>Awards</p>
        </div>

        <div class="deat">
          <h2>160</h2>
          <p>Employees</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clients">
      <a id="client"
        ><img
          src="https://ld-wt73.template-help.com/wt_prod-18959/images/clients-9-270x117.png"
          alt="mittos"
      /></a>
      <a
        ><img
          src="https://ld-wt73.template-help.com/wt_prod-18959/images/clients-10-270x117.png"
          alt="mittos"
      /></a>
      <a
        ><img
          src="https://ld-wt73.template-help.com/wt_prod-18959/images/clients-3-270x117.png"
          alt="mittos"
      /></a>
      <a
        ><img
          src="https://ld-wt73.template-help.com/wt_prod-18959/images/clients-11-270x117.png"
          alt="mittos"
      /></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Almost except there is still that white gap above the '12 awards' and '160 employees' bit

Comment: Okay I edited my answer. If you want the boxes a little smaller you can just reduce the height on `.deat`. I've found this most recent solution is a little more responsive to screen size too.